# Why UDP multicasts not received on my sockets?

Tags: windows, sockets, udp, multicast, upnp

I have computer with three network interfaces - one real and two VMWare virtual. I want to receive multicast messages from UPNP devices on port 1900.

I try to enum all adapters and create one socket per adapter. Also, I set socket option ReuseAddr, turn off ExclusiveAddrUse socket option, and add each socket to multicast group 239.255.255.250. And I bind socket to the addr: InterfaceAddr:1900

The problem is that only one socket receives messages - one of VMWare net sockets. `netstat -a -o -p UDP >netstat.txt` shows me that all my sockets are listening:

```
Proto  Local address          Peer address                           PID    App
UDP    0.0.0.0:1900           *:*                                    5248   uTorrent
UDP    127.0.0.1:1900         *:*                                    3932   myApp
UDP    127.0.0.1:1900         *:*                                    1400   svchost
UDP    192.168.0.100:1900     *:*                                    3932   myApp
UDP    192.168.0.100:1900     *:*                                    1400   svchost
UDP    192.168.139.1:1900     *:*                                    1400   svchost
UDP    192.168.139.1:1900     *:*                                    3932   myApp       +
UDP    192.168.180.1:1900     *:*                                    1400   svchost
UDP    192.168.180.1:1900     *:*                                    3932   myApp
```

Only socket marked with '+' receives UPNP multicasts. But Wireshark shows me that there are many other packets which are not received by me. Where is my wrong?

**UPD1** My code is runing on the host (Windows 7), and there is no virtual machines running at that moment. I have some UPNP devices (router etc) in my real net - 192.168.0.* which are also sends some notifications, but I can't receive them. UPNP NOTIFY messages over virtual network 192.168.139.* are sent by host (ms player/renderer/etc). Such notifications also are sent over all available networks, but I receive them only on 192.168.139.1 interface.

**UPD2** I rewrite my code to use single socket and bind it to INADDR_ANY:1900. First time when I starts new version all works fine - I receive all UPNP messages from all devices over my virtual or real networks. But next time when I start my application, I can see that notifications from only 192.168.139.* net are received - all is as in starting question.

**UPD3** I turn off all virtual network adapters and keep on only real adapter. In this configuration both versions of code (one socket binded to all addresses/one socket per interface) works fine.

**About MCVE** It is not so easy to make MCVE, so now I'm trying to understand by the symptoms what occur.

**Pseudo code**

```
hSock = :: socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP );

u_long nb = 1;
::ioctlsocket( hSock, FIONBIO, &nb);

reuseAddrSet(hSock, TRUE);
reusePortSet(hSock, TRUE);

if (useSingleSocket)
    bindSocket(hSock, "any-addr");
else
    bindSocket(hSock, "interface-addr");

broadcastModeSet(hSock, TRUE);

setSockOption( hSock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, { "any-addr", "239.255.255.250" } );
```

**UPD4** I found next note about multicasting (here - http://www4.ncsu.edu/~rhee/clas/csc495j/mcast.api.txt):

> Every membership is associated with a single interface, and it is
>   possible to join the same group on more than one interface. 
>   "imr_interface" should be INADDR_ANY to choose the default multicast
>   interface, or one of the host's local addresses to choose a particular
>   (multicast-capable) interface. Up to IP_MAX_MEMBERSHIPS (currently 20)
>   memberships may be added on a single socket.

As followed from note above, the code

```
setSockOption( hSock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, { "any-addr", "239.255.255.250" }
```

adds only default multicast interface to multicast group, and not for all interfaces, as I assumed initially. So, I need to enum interfaces and call

```
setSockOption( hSock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, { "interface-addr", "239.255.255.250" }
```

for single socket, or call it for each per-interface socket with the same address as used to bind soxket.

I'm right?

Comment: Is this code running on the VMWare host or client? What sort of virtual network interface? Bridge, Host-only, or NAT?

Comment: Please show your actual code that is creating and binding the sockets to the local adapters and then subscribing them to the multicast group.

Comment: You don't need a socket per adapter. You just need to join the multicast group via all adapters, and to bind the socket to 0.0.0.0.

Comment: Re your edit and final question, that is exactly what I just said in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

As written in UPD4 the socket user MUST add the socket to multicast group using interface address. Using INADDR_ANY when adding socket to multicast group adds only default multicast interface to multicast group, so the only one interface can receive multicast messages.

Also, as we know, there is an OS limit for number of socket's multicast groups, and so more pretty way is to create one socket per each network interface.

Comment: *Where* exactly is that written? I've never seen it. Your contention about the 'default multicast interface' isn't correct, partly because there is no such thing. You can join a multicast group via any interface, and you frequently have to loop joining via all of them.

Comment: When I rewrite my code to conform the note above, it's starts to work. This is the main criteria, which I believe

Comment: When you make a claim that something 'is written' somewhere and you are asked to substantiate it by providing a citation, the idea is that you either do so or withdraw. The fact that your code works does not prove that it 'is written' anywhere. I have code that supports my claim too but I'm not claiming it 'is written' anywhere. It does however disprove your claim that it must be done your way.

Comment: If found this informaition here - http://www4.ncsu.edu/~rhee/clas/csc495j/mcast.api.txt in "Receiving IP Multicast Datagrams" section

Comment: It's 25 years old, and it doesn't disagree with what I stated.

Comment: But it works for me, and not works when I add socket to multicast group using INADDR_ANY interface address. Why this can be? Have any suggestions?

Comment: Because the default route to the multicast address on your specific computer isn't the interface via which you are receiving multicasts. You still haven't fixed your answer. Link broken.